# fn_dblog выбирает данные только за последний час?

Tags: sql-server

В MSSQL 2016 столкнулся с `fn_dblog`. Нужно посмотреть лог, например за вчера

Смотрим что уже есть (я так думаю)

```
 select *  from sys.dm_db_log_info(null)  where vlf_active = 1
 --database_id  vlf_first_lsn           vlf_create_lsn
 --11           000046e4:00000010:0001  000046d6:0001d550:0001
```

Получаем цифры lsn. При попытке посмотреть vlf_first_lsn получаю ответ пусто .

```
SELECT [Current LSN],           Operation ,    [Begin time] FROM ::fn_dblog('18148:16:1', '18148:16:4') 
 -- пусто
SELECT [Current LSN],           Operation ,    [Begin time] FROM ::fn_dblog('18148:120144:1', '18148:120144:4') 
-- пусто

SELECT [Current LSN],           Operation ,    [Begin time] FROM ::fn_dblog(null, null) 
        000046e4:0002c1f8:0001  LOP_BEGIN_XACT  2023/03/20 17:21:31:770
```

(на момент выборки было около 2023/03/20 18:00)

000046e4  =18148 ("сегмент")

00000010 = 16

0001d550 = 120144

0002c1f8  =180728

`0002c1f8` - это очень далеко в логе. Что это за ограничение, как можно посмотреть другие части лога? Может база в каком то режиме, может есть какие-то опции?

Comment: А какая модель восстановления? `SELECT recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = 11`?

Comment: @i-one recovery model = FULL (вернуло)

Comment: Если я правильно помню, *fn_dblog* только активную часть лога показывает. Думаю надо пробовать читать из бэкапов лога (с помощью *fn_dump_dblog*).

Comment: @i-one я не понял как ею пользоваться. На работающей БД указал имя файла - "файл занят другим приложением", я перевёл бд в offline - новая ошибка "файл имеет не тот формат". Строка `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM fn_dump_dblog ( NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, имяфайла_на_сервере.ldf,...`  может что не так указываю(

Comment: Нет, нет, не из живого `.ldf` читать, а из `.bak`-ов журнала транзакций. Раз модель восстановления FULL, то, по идее, должны быть настроены бэкапы лога с какой-то периодичностью. Т.е. я подозреваю, что "вчерашнее" уже не в активной части лога, а где-то в бэкапах.

Comment: Ничего не настроено всё в нуле.  Тупо журнал на 33гига. Пробую сделать бекап...  Набрал `backup log mydb_log to mydb_log1` пишет проверьте `sys.backup_devices`. Посмотрел - там пусто... понял... буду копать инструкции на мелкософте как сделать бекап лога. Спасибо за подсказку...

Comment: Подождите, оказывается есть способ заставить *fn_dblog* читать не только активную часть лога. Попробуйте `DBCC TRACEON(2537); SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL);`.

Comment: DBCC TRACEON(2537);  - помогло, дало с `000046e4:00000010:0001` смотреть лог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-умолчанию *fn_dblog* читает данные только активной части журнала транзакций. Но при включенном флаге трассировки 2537 (упоминается [здесь](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/finding-out-who-dropped-a-table-using-the-transaction-log/)) может читать и неактивную часть:

```
DBCC TRACEON(2537);

SELECT *
FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL);
```

Если же данные за прошлый период находятся уже не в самом журнале, а в одном из его бэкапов, то использование *fn_dblog* не поможет (даже со включенным флагом). В таком случае следует воспользоваться *sys.fn_dump_dblog*:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_dump_dblog(
    NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, N'D:\DB_log_20230320_120000.bak',
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
    DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```